# sql function parameter in function return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

sql view in how can I return the return value from the function into the function

```
select 

dbo.fn_CalculatePrice
(
p.Price, 
p.CargoPrice, 
p.Factor, 
p.PointRatio,
null, 
p.OperactivePromoCode, 
SELECT IncludingCargoPrice FROM [dbo].[fn_Parameter](),
SELECT IncludingProductKdv FROM [dbo].[fn_Parameter]()) AS Price 
From Product as p

[dbo].[fn_CalculatePrice] func parameters
(
    @Price money,
    @CargoPrice money,
    @CatFactor decimal(8,4), 
    @PointRatio decimal(8,4),
    @HBFactor decimal(8,4),
    @PromoCode nvarchar(50),
    @includingCargoPrice bit,
    @includingProductKdv bit
)

fn_Parameter func return table
{
IncludingCargoPrice bit,
IncludingProductKdv bit,
}
```

**Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'**

Comment: To begin with, having a `SELECT` statement as a parameter of a function is... (how to say is...?) not a recommended practice. Second, the `From Product as p` is obviously misplaced. Third, the selects within the parameters list do not warrant that they return a single value. Last, EDIT your question an make it readable,.

Comment: be aware that scalar valued functions perform RBAR (row by agonising row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of these 2 approaches:

1) Determine each parameter as a scalar variable.

```
DECLARE @IncludingCargoPrice BIT = (SELECT IncludingCargoPrice FROM [dbo].fn_Parameter())
DECLARE @IncludingProductKdv BIT = (SELECT IncludingProductKdv FROM [dbo].fn_Parameter())

SELECT
    dbo.fn_CalculatePrice(
        p.Price, 
        p.CargoPrice, 
        p.Factor, 
        p.PointRatio,
        null, 
        p.OperactivePromoCode, 
        @IncludingCargoPrice,
        @IncludingProductKdv) AS Price
From 
    Product as p
```

2) `SELECT` them directly in your query (must make sure that the parameter table only contains one row, or the function will be applied multiple times for each product, by parameter row). You can filter the rows with `WHERE` or with a condition in an `INNER JOIN` (instead of a `CROSS JOIN` which I wrote as example).

```
SELECT
    dbo.fn_CalculatePrice(
        p.Price, 
        p.CargoPrice, 
        p.Factor, 
        p.PointRatio,
        null, 
        p.OperactivePromoCode, 
        X.IncludingCargoPrice,
        X.IncludingProductKdv) AS Price
From 
    Product as p
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].fn_Parameter() AS X
```